# Can an iPad/iPhone app intercept media keys from a keyboard?

Tags: iphone, sdk

Is it possible for an iPad/iPhone app to intercept the play/pause/rwd/fwd keys on a connected keyboard? I've heard that it can but cannot find a reference to it.

Comment: Have you tried pressing those keys to see if your app receives them?

Answer (score 0):

I believe external keyboard media keys work through the same API as the controls in the multitasking UI and on the mic/headset cord. Events from those come in as [`UIEvent` remote control events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/RemoteControl/RemoteControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7).